# Common attacks when no ports are open

Tags: ddos, injection, ports

If you have a web server with all ports closed (except, of course, the necessary HTTP) what kind of attacks can an attacker use to hack into the system? Are the only vulnerabilities stuff like injection attacks or DDoS attacks? If there are some, how could you defend against them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An attacker can still use the full range of attacks on the webserver: everything from password guessing to code injection to buffer overflows to path traversal to who-knows-what.  The only thing closing non-HTTP ports does is prevent the attacker from going after other programs that might be listening for incoming traffic (eg. a mailserver).

Comment: What about if the target is a regular computer? Any attacks for that?

Comment: Are you saying the only port exposed in a web server port on this personal computer? There's still physical and social attacks. There's out of date web server software. There's web vulnerabilities for the website that's running on that computer.

Comment: You answered my question about web servers. I asked this purely for curiosity.